# Необходимо не менее 15.7 GB места на диске для установки Ubuntu

Tags: windows, virtualbox

Устанавливаю убунту через VirtualBox, не даёт скачать так как на компьютере не хватает места, я не понимаю где у меня 8.6GB (на дисках место есть) и можно ли эту проблему решить

[image: Такая ошибка]

[image: Вот мои диски, место вроде есть.]

Comment: Ну так а в настройках виртуалбокса сколько гигов выделено под систему?

Comment: Поменял, помогло, спасибо